# Implementing CAN bus software termination

Tags: software, can, termination

I noticed that a lot of CAN new test equipment allow you to enable/disable the termination via software.  Is there an new transceiver in the market or an accepted way to implement this??

Comment: You could use an analog switch. See:http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169933/switching-a-resistor-by-software

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The analog switch will have a dramatic effect on the common-mode range and voltage limits allowed on the bus lines. CAN transceivers are made to be very tolerant regarding this (in case there is a voltage shift between the ground level on the different nodes), and you'll just nullify this by using a simple analog switch.

Comment: @dim Then MAX14759/MAX14761/MAX14763, Maxim that claims their analog switches are good for termination of RS485, CAN,...are liars.

Comment: They are *above and below the rails* analog switch. This is very particular and indeed solves the problem I mentioned. But these are not regular analog switch.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done using a bipolar solid-state relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQqdl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>